# Issue with thread in winapi c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I just want to run my thread but I get nothing in console. Guidances say that should work.
What is the problem?

Code:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFun(LPVOID q) {
    for(int i = 0;i++;i<10){
        cout << "I'm working...\n";

    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD t;
    HANDLE thr1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadFun, NULL, 0, &t);

    cout << "Main thread\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop conditional is wrong. Swap your `i++` and `i < 10`. `i++` when `i == 0` (on your first iteration) evaluates to `0` which evaluates to `false`, so you never enter your loop. You also need to block in `main` and wait for the thread to finish before exiting. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779668/2027196) for that.

Comment: I'm not entirely agreeing with the votes to close as a typo since the problem is twofold.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is wrong. The middle part should be the condition and the stepping is done in the third part. You also should wait for the started thread to finish. If your program exits before the other thread has had a chance, you may or may not see any, or part, of the output from that thread.

Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFun(LPVOID q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "I'm working...\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD t;
    HANDLE thr1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadFun, NULL, 0, &t);
    std::cout << "Main thread\n";

    if (thr1 == nullptr) std::cout << GetLastError() << '\n';
    else WaitForSingleObject(thr1, INFINITE);
}
```